# VIM: How to access the redo-register

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, refactoring, rename

As a secondary task to a Python auto-completion (https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi), I'm writing a VIM plugin with the ability to do renaming (refactoring).

The most comfortable way to do renaming is to use `cw` and `autocommand InsertLeave :call do_renaming_func()`. To do this I need to access the `redo-register` (see `help redo-register`) or something similar, which would record the written text.

If possible, I like to do this without macros, because I don't want to mess up anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not knowing which register it was, but to access it.
I eventually found the method:

```
getreg('.')
```

As @Ingo Karkat points out, this register might include some escape chars.

However, I used a different method in the end. I just read `expand('<cword>')` to get the new word (because a rename is always only one word). This is far easier and more reliable.

Here's the code (line 113):
https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/commit/6920f15caf332cd14a7833a071765dfa77d82328

Answer (score 2):

The `.` register (`@.`) contains all editing keys, unfortunately in raw form, so also `<Del>` and `<BS>`, which show up as `<80>kD`, and which insert completion does not interpret. Instead, to extract only the net text entered, use the range delimited by the marks `'[` and `']` (last one exclusive).

For an example on how to do this, have a look at my [PrevInsertComplete plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4185).

Comment: Nice.  I didn't realize this as in my simple test I didn't make typos.  +1.

Answer (score 1):

The `.` register contains the last inserted text.  See `:help quote_.`.

The help doesn't specifically mention any caveats of when this register is populated, however it does mention that it doesn't work when editing the command line.  This shouldn't be an issue for you.